# An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'. Please see the trace log for more details

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization Project that requires me to only show data (like Opportunities) that have been setup in added customization tab in Business Account. I've manage to comply these using data view delegate and a custom selector, The error occurs when:

1.) clicking an opportunity ID where the customization restricts such data in the generic inquiry.
2.) clicking next or previous button in the opportunities module

Here is the Code

```
protected virtual IEnumerable opportunity()
    {
        var output = new PXSelect<CROpportunity>(Base);
        foreach (CROpportunity _output in output.Select())
        {
            bool returnOutput = false;
            var memberships = PXSelectJoinGroupBy<EPEmployee, RightJoin<EPCompanyTreeMember, On<EPCompanyTreeMember.userID, Equal<EPEmployee.userID>>>, Where<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<EPCompanyTreeMember.workGroupID>>>.Select(Base);
            foreach (PXResult<EPEmployee, EPCompanyTreeMember> member in memberships)
            {
                EPCompanyTreeMember _member = (EPCompanyTreeMember)member;
                BAccountRestriction2 visible = PXSelect<BAccountRestriction2, Where<BAccountRestriction2.account, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>, And<BAccountRestriction2.child, Equal<Required<BAccountRestriction2.child>>>>>.Select(Base, ((CROpportunity)_output).BAccountID, _member.WorkGroupID);
                if (visible != null || ((CROpportunity)_output).OpportunityID == " <NEW>")
                {

                    returnOutput = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (returnOutput)
            {
                yield return _output;
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the Custom Selector

```
 public class OpportunityMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{

    #region custom selector
    public class PXCustomSelectorOpportunityAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
    {
        public PXCustomSelectorOpportunityAttribute()
            : base(typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityID)
               , new[] { typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityID), 
            typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityName),
            typeof(CROpportunity.status), 
            typeof(CROpportunity.curyAmount),
            typeof(CROpportunity.curyID), 
            typeof(CROpportunity.closeDate),
            typeof(CROpportunity.stageID),
            typeof(CROpportunity.cROpportunityClassID),
            typeof(BAccount.acctName),
            typeof(Contact.displayName) }
            )
        {
            //this.DescriptionField = typeof(CQHRISLeave.refNbr);
        }
        protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
        {
            foreach (var pc in this._Graph.GetExtension<OpportunityMaintExtension>().opportunity())
            {
                if (((CROpportunity)pc).OpportunityID != " <NEW>")
                    yield return pc as CROpportunity;
            }
        }


    }
    #endregion
```

And then the implementation of the custom selector attribute is here:

```
 public class CROpportunityExtension : PXCacheExtension<CROpportunity>
{
    #region OpportunityID

    public abstract class opportunityID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

    public const int OpportunityIDLength = 10;

    [PXDBString(OpportunityIDLength, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Opportunity ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [AutoNumber(typeof(CRSetup.opportunityNumberingID), typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
    [NORDE.OpportunityMaintExtension.PXCustomSelectorOpportunity]
    [PXFieldDescription]
    public virtual String OpportunityID { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to "resolve" this issue by disabling the generic inquiry on this page. Initially, Opportunities page is a generic inquiry, for some reason, it may have affected the cache or the data view delegate and throws an error.

I simply: Edit Generic inquiry -> Entry Point Tab -> Uncheck "Replace Entry Screen with this Inuiry in Menu"